# Is it forbiden to drive a car?

Tags: halacha

I remember reading an answer here saying that it was forbidden (even for men) to drive a car. That one Rabbi used to forbid it. I tried to search it but I did not find it. Maybe someone can help.

Comment: What do you mean, "even for men"? Why would men be different?

Comment: @Ypnypn, as opposed to: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29765/which-communities-do-not-allow-women-to-drive-cars

Answer (score 2):

R. Shimshon David Pinkus has a letter which is published in the end of Nefesh Shimshon on Emunah, where he very strongly discourages anyone from having a car and driving it on their own. I don't think that he objected to using public transportation or taxis though. (He also writes that while he himself has a car, his Rabbeim have told him that because of his job/position he's required to have one)

Comment: Almost prophetic, considering how he died (in a car wreck)

Comment: @Daniel I was wondering if I should mention that... it seemed too close to gloating in a horribly twisted way

Answer (score 0):

You are probably thinking of [this question and answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9262/which-rabbis-forbade-cars-100-years-ago). No one actually came up with a Rabbi there.

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question?

Comment: @Daniel, I don't know, this question was "where can I find that question". Not sure what the duplication policy is in that case. Also, this question taken on its own is more broad, as it doesn't limit to 100 years ago.