# Is one allowed to drive a car according to the Steipler?

Tags: halacha, vehicles-transportation

I heard a speaker say the Steipler held that one is not allowed to drive a car because it is potential murder is this true?

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45041/759

Comment: I don't know if you consider the following mere hearsay, but R. Sternbuch (Teshuvot V'hanhagot I:850) quotes the following story regarding the Steipler: 
ושמעתי על אחד שבא לפניו שחושש מאד שיקבל עונש חמור על שעבר על חוקי התנועה ורוצה לבקש ברכתו שיפטרו אותו, והגיב במחאה חריפה מאד, שהאמת שראוי לעונש! That is, someone supposedly violated traffic laws came to the Steipler and asked for a blessing that he be let off, but the Steipler angrily responded that he ought to be punished. | From this source alone, one might assume that he was opposed to those who violate traffic laws; not all who drive.

Comment: @mevaqesh ,wouldn't all Rabbis agree with this?

Comment: Likely; depending on the nature of the violation. | Certainly I didn't mean in any way to imply the contrary. @sam

Comment: Many years ago I read that a close student of the Stiepler quoted him as saying that if there was a beis din hagodol nowadays, they would have forbidden driving through a gzeirah or takanah. I don't believe that the Stiepler is correct about that (if he said it) but he is quoted to that effect.

Comment: @sam Absolutely not. Unfortunately. They start saying strange things about saving yidden. There were petitions going around to save this guy! https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Grossman

Answer (score 1):

In the biography on Rav Chaim Kanievsky entitled *Rebbetzin Kanievsky*, there are stories of the Steipler taking taxis. I recall one story where he takes a cab to pick up his son at the bus on an erev Shabbos.

Comment: It may nevertheless be forbidden to drive the car itself.

Comment: Its forbidden to drive a car on Shabbos and its forbidden to cause someone to drive a car on Shabbos even if he drives a taxi.

Comment: I fail to see your point. Causing others to to perform activities that a person himself is forbidden from performing, is often forbidden. However a) this rule is not universal. b) it is missing from your answer, anyway. Vital information should always be edited into posts themselves.

Comment: @YK That is not the point. The question and answer deal with driving a car when it is not forbidden for other reasons. Thus, driving being forbidden on Shabbos does not apply.

Comment: That is a strange name for a biography of Rav Chaim Kanievsky.